# Move Ecb in Document Library

Tags: document-library, ecb-menu

How can I move the ecb (edit control block/context menu) from column "Name" to "Title" in a document-library? I know how to do It via SP-Designer, but would prefer a code-solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already tried this:  SPList DocLib = aktWeb.Lists[Libname];
                        SPField field = DocLib.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");

                        field.ListItemMenu = true;
                        field.ListItemMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;

                        field.Update();

                        DocLib.Update(); But field.ListItemMenuAllowed gets resetted to SPField.ListItemMenuState.Allowed and I don't know why and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted works...... BUT not on column "Title". Every other column can be modified. I will use a calculated column showing title's content, bind the ecb to it and use it instead of "title".